How to set Parent for Tabitems if the Items are Dynamic WPF
XAML:
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- This is the one I use and it has no parent-->
        <TabControl x:Name="hasNoParent" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=mainWin}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

C#:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
public List Items { get; set; } = new List { "a", "b", "c" };
public MainWindow()
{

    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var oControl = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

    while (oControl != null && !(oControl is TabItem))
    {
        oControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(oControl);
    }

    if (oControl is TabItem con)
    {
        var parent = (TabControl)con.Parent;
    }

    base.OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
}

}
How can I set the parents for 'TabItem' that are dynamically added(using ItemSource) so that I can access it using '  var parent = (TabControl)con.Parent;'  at the moment the parent for each 'TabItem' is null.
I tried this and I was able to see and use the Parent without doing anything which is not dynamic:
<TabControl  x:Name="hasParent" >
    <TabItem Header="1"></TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2"></TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="3"></TabItem>
</TabControl>


If you attach an event handler to the TabControl instead of overriding the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp method of the window, you can easily get a reference to the parent TabControl by casting the first argument. But what exactly are you trying to do here?

FrameworkElement.Parent only returns the logical parent and is set by the framework.
When you add the items to the ItemsControl.ItemsSource then the ItemsControl internally generates the containers for the items. In case of the TabControl the generated item containers are of type TabItem. The generated TabItem containers (or generated item containers of an ItemsControl in general) are not the direct logical child of the TabControl. They are a child of the internal Panel that hosts and actually generates the item containers.
You must use the VisualTreeHelper to find the TabControl which is only a visual parent TabControl.
On the other hand, if you add the item containers to the ItemsControl explicitly (you don't use the ItemsSource to make the Panel of the ItemsControl to generate the containers for you), then those containers are directly added to the logical tree of the ItemsControl. The Panel is not involved in either generating containers or hosting them. Therefore, their Parent property is set to the ItemsControl that owns them and is their direct logical parent.
You are currently handling the mouse event for the MainWindow (by providing the override).
If you handle the event directly on the TabControl your code becomes significantly simpler as you don't have to use the VisualTreeHelper to get the parent TabControl:
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items, ElementName=mainWin}"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="OnTabControlPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />

private void OnTabControlPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  // The TabControl that is the visual parent of the clicked item container
  var tabControl = (TabControl)sender;

  // The item inside the ItemsSource
  object clickedTabItem = tabControl.SelectedItem;

  // The clicked TabItem container
  int clickedTabItemIndex = tabControl.SelectedIndex;
  var clickedTabItemContainer = (TabItem)tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(clickedTabItemIndex);
}

